# Definition of constant within namespace in cpp file

Tags: c++

I've approached this strange ( for me ) effect in VS 2010.
Can anyone smart shed some light on it please.

```
//Header.h
#include <string>
namespace MySpace {
extern const std::string SOME_CONST_STRING;
}

//Implementation.cpp
#include "Header.h"
using namespace MySpace;
const std::string SOME_CONST_STRING = "CONST_STRING_VALUE";
```

This causes linker to output error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol const MySpace::SOME_CONST_STRING.

However when I change Implementation.cpp like this:

```
//Implementation.cpp
#include "Header.h"
namespace MySpace {
const std::string SOME_CONST_STRING = "CONST_STRING_VALUE";    
}
```

the code builds OK.

Is it good example for prefering defining of namespace in cpp file rather than using it ?

Comment: I don't understand your last question, I'm afraid.

Comment: SOME_CONST_STRING in cpp also needs extern.

Comment: The only difference in two versions of Implementation.cpp is using namespace MySpace; vs namespace MySpace { ... }. First one fails to link, while second links OK.

Comment: Joseph. I saw it in "coding style" questions: what is prefered way of writing it in cpp files: using namespace MySpace; vs namespace MySpace { ... }. There were few examples which one is better over the other. I'm asking if the problem above is good reason to not write using namespace MySpace; in implementation cpp files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively write:

```
const std::string MySpace::SOME_CONST_STRING = "CONST_STRING_VALUE";
```

That name is declared inside `MySpace` so you have to refer to it as such.

Comment: SOME_CONST_STRING in cpp also needs extern.

Comment: @NeilKirk It doesn't. In fact, it can't.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "namespace" in your using. It should be like this:

```
#include "Header.h"
using namespace MySpace;
const std::string SOME_CONST_STRING = "CONST_STRING_VALUE";
```

Comment: Thanks Johan this is just a "typo" in the question. I'll edit it.

Comment: SOME_CONST_STRING in cpp also needs extern.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure your code doesn't work. How does it know SOME_CONST_STRING is in MySpace and not the global namespace?

Comment: No it doesn't, "extern" in header is sufficent. That part is OK. ;)

Comment: The only difference in two versions of Implementation.cpp is using namespace MySpace; vs namespace MySpace { ... }. First one fails to link, while second links OK.

Comment: @jakumate ok I've asked question here to find more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698515/is-extern-keyword-required-here-const-in-cpp-file

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of namespaces is that names in a particular namespace are independent of names outside that namespace.  A program could have both a `MySpace::SOME_CONST_STRING` *and* a global `::SOME_CONST_STRING`, and these are two completely unrelated symbols.  It would be wrong for the linker to use a definition of one to satisfy a reference to the other.

When you define a variable, you have to define it in the namespace where you want it to be.