# Is extern keyword required here, const in cpp file

Tags: c++

If I have in header file

```
namespace Bob
{
    extern const T x;
};
```

And in source file

```
extern const T Bob::x = 123;
```

Is the second `extern` in the source file required or optional?

I've searched and found conflicting information.

From this webpage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh.aspx

*But to get the same behavior in C++, you must declare your const variable [in source file] as:*

```
extern const int i = 2;
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How come you can write really small comments?

Comment: @NeilKirk he's a cool guy, we aren't :)

Comment: To be honest I'm no more enlightened on this matter after the answers and comments.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the `extern` keyword tells the compiler not to define a symbol, because it will be defined somewhere else. So writing e.g.

```
namespace Bob {
    extern T x;
}
```

does not define the variable `x`, but rather declares it. You can have as many `extern` declarations as you like. However, if you do not provide a definition the linking will fail. So you have to define

```
T Bob::x;
```

somewhere in the code in order to provide the definition.

The `const` keyword is a little special here, because it implies internal linkage. This means, that the definition of `x` will not be visible outside the specific compilation unit where it was defined. To alter this behavior you do need to write

```
    extern const T Bob::x = 123;
```

if you want `x` to be `const` and also reference it from other compilation units.

**----yet another edit----**
Just to be absolutely clear:
If a `const` variable is supposed to be referenced outside of its compilation unit, then you **must** explicitly declare it `extern`.

However, if the declaration is given separately from the definition, then the definition does not necessarily need to specify the keyword `extern` again. Yet another example for demonstration:

**myheader.h**

```
extern const int i;
```

This declares `i` a `const` integer with external linkage, but does not define it.

**main.cpp, version 1**

```
#include "myheader.h" //Through the include, the above declaration of `i` comes before its definition.

const int i=123; // Although the `extern` modifier is omitted here,
                 // it's still in effect because we already declared `i` as `extern`
                 // Therefore it makes no difference here, whether or not you specify `extern` again.
                 // The compiler knows this is a definition either way, because of the initialization.
```

**main.cpp, version 2**

```
//#include "myheader.h"

extern const int i=123; // this line is declaration and definition in one, because we did not include
                        // the declaration from myheader.h. Thus, to tell the compiler that you want
                        // `i` with external linkage, you MUST specify `extern`. Otherwise you'll get
                        // internal linkage.
```

I hope all this now makes sense to you.

Comment: Does "neither required nor optional" mean "not allowed"?

Comment: No, it is allowed but change the meaning. If extern is present you can use the variable but not define it.

Comment: you don't need the `extern` in the definition, as long as you `#include` the header file that declares it as `extern`. It's safer that way too.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: I agree, that it's not needed if we include the extern declaration before the definition, but why would it be safer?

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich : including the header will protect you from accidental differences between declaration and definition. Additionally, not adding the `extern` in the definition means it will only have external linkage when it needs to (when the declaration is removed from the header file, it'll automatically revert to internal linkage)

Comment: Just to clarify, as you changed your answer quite a bit, you are saying the second extern IS required?

Comment: @NeilKirk : the `extern` in the definition is required if you don't `#include` the header file. Otherwise it's not required (ref. my previous comments).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I would include the header file but don't want it to break if I don't. So it's safer to always provide extern?

Comment: @NeilKirk : it's safer to always include the header file, and not put the `extern` in the definition. For reasons, ref. my previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the linkage of a symbol with the `static` and `extern` keywords. The default linkage is `extern` for non-const symbols and `static` (i.e. internal) for const symbols at namespace scope. This is valid for C++ but not for C (where you would have to declare it as `static` to make it have internal linkage).

So if you have

```
const int i = 2;
```

into a .c file and you use it into another unit by declaring

```
extern const int i;
```

that's fine in C since that variable has external linkage by default (and with the extern keyword you're instructing the compiler to find it into another unit), but in C++ the same

```
const int i = 2;
```

into a .cpp file (firmstanding what I wrote) has internal linkage and it would have to be defined with

```
extern const int i = 2;
```

to explicitly have external linkage and be able to be used into another unit with

```
extern const int i;
```

Finally when you initialize a global variable you're always **defining it** in the module where you're doing it, this means that the following is perfectly valid:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define T int

extern const T x; // This is a declaration
extern const T x = 123; // This is a definition

int main() {

  std::cout << x; // 123

  return 0;
}
```

That means the second 'extern' keyword is also unnecessary.

Comment: So your answer is no, it's not required? This is different to the other answer.

Comment: That is bad. I got burnt by this before on two different compilers treating a missing extern on a const differently. I can't simply experiment on one compiler. Also, my question is about different files.

Comment: @NeilKirk compilers should do the same thing as long as they conform to the standard. Make sure you're not compiling part of the code as C and some other stuff as C++. Also make sure you're using the right extern keyword on the declaration.

Comment: They should, but they don't. I've had VS and gcc act differently when missing a required extern keyword. It was in a huge project so hard to simplify.

Comment: @NeilKirk It might have been a bug or something similar (in MSVC perhaps) but this should be the behavior they should conform to. I can't help you with your previous project, sorry.